# Hessian of the minimal point

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

Assume $f(x,y)$ is a convex function, and $(\hat{x},\hat{y})$ is the global minimum, where the Hessian matrix is assumed to be positive-definite.

Here, we denote $h(x)=\min_y f(x,y)$. Obviously, the minimum of $h(x)$ is obtained at $\hat{x}$. Can we say that the Hessian matrix of $h(x)$ at $\hat{x}$ is positive-definite?

Comment: By Taylor, $h(x + t) = h(x) + h'(x) \cdot t + h''(x) \cdot (t,t) + o(\|t\|^2) = h(x) + h''(x) \cdot (t,t) + o(\|t\|^2).$ You can consider $t = \varepsilon v,$ for any vector $v,$ and then factor $\varepsilon,$ to reach $0\leq h(x+t)-h(x) = \varepsilon^2 (h''(x) \cdot (v,v) + o(\varepsilon^2)/\varepsilon^2),$ the quantity inside parenthesis must be $\geq 0,$ hence $h''(x)$ is positive semidefinite. The argument cannot prove positive definite as $x^4$ shows with a minimum at $x = 0.$

Comment: @William M, thanks! I have changed the question, and I want to prove the case for positive-definite. Do you mean that only positive-semidefinite can be proved?

Comment: Here, I assume that $f(x,y)$ is given, and not arbitrary. Thus, we can let the Hessian of its minimum be positive-definite.

Comment: I would strongly suspect it is not the case, try $h(x,y) = x^4 + y^2.$

Comment: For $f(x,y)=x^4+y^2$, the Hessian at $(0,0)$ is not PD, thus it doesn't meet the assumption.

Comment: What about $x^4(1 + y^2)$?